# Siempre problemas con el Style.css en Github Pages, cómo aplico los styles del tema de Jekyll?

Tags: css, github, style

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe cómo resolver este problema o conoce Jekyll como para saber qué configuración cambiar?

les paso mi _config.yaml que configuré como debería para usar con Pages

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es la configuración entre tu baseurl y la variable url. Puedes revisar esta explicación:

[Confusión entre baseurl y url](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/344982)